# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'src' Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I tried to use a JavaScript variable to generate multiple directories when copying my files like this:

```
var foo = '{expand:true,cwd:path1,src:"**",dest:path2,fliter:"isFile",flatten:true},
{expand:true,cwd:path3,src:"**",dest:path4,fliter:"isFile",flatten:true},';


module.exports = function (grunt) {


    grunt.initConfig({

copy: {
     main: {
         files:[foo]
           }
      }
})

}
```

This throws me the ERROR:

`Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'src' in` `{expand:true,cwd:path1,src:"**",dest:path2,fliter:"isFile",flatten:true},{expand:true,cwd:path3,src:"**",dest:path4,fliter:"isFile",flatten:true}`,

**when i paste the Content of the variable in, it works.**

Is there any solution to this?

thanks :)

Comment: What's `fliter`? Try defining the value of `foo` as an Object instead of a String? For example: `var foo = {expand:true,cwd:path1,src:"**",dest:path2,filter:"isFile",flatten:true}, {expand:true,cwd:path3,src:"**",dest:path4,filter:"isFile",flatten:true};`

Comment: Hey @RobC, Thanks for the quick reply!

Adding multiple Objects into an Array actually worked for me! :)

thanks a lot, have a great day!